# Create a dynamic column in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have the following problem. I have a table like such:

| CLIENT | DATE | TARGET | SALES ON DEP. A | SALES ON DEP. B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AMADOR | 01/02/2022 | aaaa | 10 | 0 |
| JOHN | 01/02/2022 | xxxx | 12 | 13 |
| JACK | 02/02/2022 | xxxx | 5 | 12 |
| MARIA | 03/02/2022 | xxxx | 5 | 5 |
| AMADOR | 02/02/2022 | aaaa | 0 | 4 |
| AMADOR | 05/02/2022 | aaaa | 0 | 6 |
| MARIA | 05/02/2022 | cccc | 4 | 0 |
| BLAIR | 06/02/2022 | cccc | 5 | 2 |
| JACK | 06/02/2022 | cccc | 0 | 2 |

let's say I want to show that table as a matrix, without the column "DATE". "DATE" will beocme a slicer, and I want to create a second slicer called "STATE" which has the following logic:

- if sum(dep A)>0 and sum(dep B)>0 ---> state = shared
- if sum(dep A)>0 and sum(dep B)=0 ---> state = only A
- if sum(dep A)=0 and sum(dep B)>0 ---> state = only B
- if sum(dep A)=0 and sum(dep B)=0 ---> state = other

If I do the logic explained earlier as a calculated measure it works fine, as the measure recalculates itself when the date filter changes. However, when I put the same code as a calculated column, it doesnt respond to the date filter. The idea is, if for example, the date range selected is: 01/02/2022 to 03/02/2022 the table should be something like this:

| CLIENT | TARGET | sum(DEP. A) | sum( DEP. B) | STATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AMADOR | aaaa | 10 | 4 | shared |
| JOHN | xxxx | 12 | 13 | shared |
| JACK | xxxx | 5 | 12 | shared |
| MARIA | xxxx | 5 | 5 | shared |

However, if the date selection was 02/02/2022 to 05/02/2022, the output table should be:

| CLIENT | TARGET | sum(DEP. A) | sum( DEP. B) | STATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AMADOR | aaaa | 0 | 10 | only B |
| JACk | xxxx | 5 | 12 | shared |
| MARIA | xxxx | 5 | 5 | shared |
| MARIA | cccc | 4 | 0 | only A |

The reason for which I need "STATE" to be a calculated column and NOT a measure is becasue I need to display it as a filter pane. Please help! I have tried to create a DAX table, but doesnt work, I have tried to create a "map" table with one column with the different possible values of state (let's call it column aux) and try to create a relationship between 'aux' and the calculated measure but of course that doesnt work either... please help!

Comment: Calculated columns are calculated only once, when the data is loaded. That's why it will not respond to the slicer. Make a static table with one column `STATE` and `shared`, `only A`, `only B` and `other` values. Use that table for filtering and adjust the logic of your report.

Comment: yep, that is what i ended up doing, thanks for the inspo!